# Sound Design Reel Feedback

Tags: gameaudio, demo-reel, video-games

Hey All -

Long time reader of the site. I just finished my reel consisting of all of the video game titles I've worked on during my career so far, and wanted some feedback.

In particular - I have a lot of titles on my resume, though they are mostly sports games. Does a single type of sound design limit what potential employers think you are capable of?

Thanks

[youtube]LGb52su5gOM[/youtube]

Answer (score 1):

@Justin hey Justin, I just watched your video with some friends and we all liked it, we noticed some important things you may want to know though.  In the basketball ones, the sound from the actual ball was not noticeable! that is something we really felt you missed, and the shoes' squeaks where too loud and repetitive, you should have some more variations for those. Later one, everything was really cool! the ambiences where really cool and the football one sounded just like madden in my opinion.

I hope this helps you!
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

visually, don't be afraid to push the font size of your titles/descriptions. They're way too small right now.

Answer (score 0):

Some great advice I got early on with my game audio reels:

- Keep Them Under a Minute
- Put Strongest Material First
- Don't Mix Sound Design with Music

So I think you just need to cut this down to the absolute highlights you're most proud of.  And be sure to tailor your reel specifically if you apply to new studios--in the same way you'd do with your resume and cover letter. Seems like a great start for getting on another sports related game project!